# Mobile site forgets scroll position in Chrome for Android

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mobile-web, usability, android

1. Visit a page displaying a list of questions, such as [the front page of Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), in the mobile version using [Chrome for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome).
2. Scroll down.
3. View a question from the list.
4. Go back to the question list.
5. **The question list will be scrolled to the top, rather than staying in its previous position with the viewed question visible.**

This makes it a bit tedious to browse questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't replicate this on the current version (nor in other mobile browsers).

Comment: Neither can I. Looks like something happen to fix this in the site or in Chrome sometime in the last year :)